Missing plot area in ContourPlot
The invocation
ContourPlot[-(Cos[3  ArcTan[x, y]]/ (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]^3)), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 3], 
 Contours -> 50]

produces
What is going on with the blank area around the negative x-axis, and how can I get rid of it?

You can set the option Exclusions -> None to not add exclusions:
ContourPlot[-(Cos[3   ArcTan[x, y]]/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]^3)), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 3], 
Contours -> 50, Exclusions -> None]



Thank you so much. I don't know how I missed that in the help.

@rogerl It's a pleasure to help!

By rewriting the function to eliminate Cos[3 ArcTan[x, y]], you remove the discontinuity.
-(Cos[3   ArcTan[x, y]]/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]^3)) // TrigToExp // 
  ComplexExpand // Together

$$
(-x^3 + 3 x y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^3
$$
ContourPlot[-(x^3 - 3  x  y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^3, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 3], 
 Contours -> 50]



That's great, but this is actually an MWE taken from a much larger computation where it may not be so easy to do that. Can you explain why there is a discontinuity to begin with? Is it because ArcTan is close to pi for angles in the second quadrant and to -pi in the third?

@rogerl   ArcTan is close to pi for angles in the second quadrant and to -pi in the third
